# VC-dimension and fundamental theorem

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

I do not understand why the correct answer is what is written below, and how it follows from the fundamental theorem of learning theory.
I thought it was connected to weak learners, but according to what is written in the explanation, this is not true.[image]

Q:
Let X be a finite set of size greater than 10^6. Which of the following statements is correct?

A:
Fix delta = 1/2, epsilon = 1/8. There exists a positive integer m such that for
every algorithm A, there exist distribution D over X and function f :
X -> {0,1} such that with a probability of at least delta  over the generation
of a training data, S, of m examples, it holds that
 L_(D,f)(A(S)) >= epsilon.